# JavaScript code to show data list in a table in front end of CRUD Asp.Net Core MVC application

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I followed a tutorial about CRUD with ASP.NET Core MVC and I was able to run the project. It lists, adds, edits, and removes Employees from a table in an SQL Server DB. Then, for improving my skills, I decided to add to the Empleado (employee) "structure" a variable list of Telefono (phone number) objects, which are stored in another table in the DB, and are linked to its own Empleado object through the idEmpleado FK. So each Empleado can be linked to 0, 1, or more Telefono objects. The project's backend is all perfect. My problem comes with JavaScript code. Below I show the function that reads the HttpGet request (the Employee list from the DB) which I added a function that reads each Empleado's Telefono's variable list (I already checked that the C# method is executed fine) in order to add the phone numbers to a  (dropdown list) in the cells of the Employee list, but this function is always returning an empty array of objects. I read over there that you can only call response.json() once, but ¿even though I call it from another function in my function? Whatever it is, ¿would someone tell me how to solve this?
Please don´t mark my question as bad or wrong or whatever. Someones did that before and I was threatened by the site of being blocked of asking any more. I'm just a Ssr desktop apps and videogame developer who wants to learn web development and I ask my questions the best I can. If something in this question is not clear please tell me and I'll try to clarify.
Thank you very much!

```js
    // loads Employee list and builds the list in the front end
function MostrarEmpleados() {
    var telefonos = [];
    var className, i = 0;

    fetch("/Home/listaEmpleados")
        .then(response => {
            return response.ok ? response.json() : Promise.reject(response)
        })
        .then(responseJson => {
            if (responseJson.length > 0) {
                $("#tablaEmpleados tbody").html("");

                i = 0;
                responseJson.forEach((empleado) => {

                    className = "telefonos" + i;
                    $("#tablaEmpleados tbody").append(
                        $("<tr>").append(
                            $("<td>").text(empleado.nombreCompleto),
                            $("<td>").addClass(className),
                            $("<td>").text(empleado.refDepartamento.nombre),
                            $("<td>").text(empleado.sueldo),
                            $("<td>").text(empleado.fechaContrato),
                            $("<td>").append(
                                $("<button>").addClass("btn btn-primary btn-sm boton-editar-empleado").text("Editar").data("dataEmpleado",empleado),
                                $("<button>").addClass("btn btn-danger btn-sm ms-2 boton-eliminar-empleado").text("Eliminar").data("dataEmpleado",empleado),
                            )
                        )
                    )
                    telefonos = ObtenerTelefonos(empleado.idEmpleado); // always returns empty array
                    $("." + className).append(
                        $("<select>").addClass("listaTels")
                    );
                    telefonos.forEach((telefono) => {
                        $(".listaTels").append(
                            $("<option>").text(telefono.descripcion + ": " + telefono.numero)
                        )
                    })
                    i++;
                })
            }
        })
}
```

Below I show the function that gets Telefono variable list from a specific Empleado. Always returning empty array.

```js
function ObtenerTelefonos(id) {

    var telefonos = [];

    fetch(`/Telefono/listaTelefonos?idEmpleado=${id}`)
        .then(response => {
            return response.ok ? response.json() : Promise.reject(response)
        })
        .then(responseJson => {
            if (responseJson.length > 0) {

                responseJson.forEach((telefono) => {
                    telefonos.push({
                        idTelefono: telefono.idTelefono,
                        descripcion: telefono.descripcion,
                        numero: telefono.numero,
                        idEmpleado: telefono.idEmpleado
                    });
                })
            }
        })
    return telefonos;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning the `telefonos` array before it is populated with data. You need to wait for the data to get back.

You need to convert it to a promise, and then wait for the data to return from the fetch function. You can then get the response in the other function where you can wrap that in a `.then` to use the response from your other function.

`telefonos = ObtenerTelefonos(empleado.idEmpleado);` --> change to `ObtenerTelefonos(empleado.idEmpleado).then(telefonos => {...code here})`

```js
function ObtenerTelefonos(id) {
    return fetch(`/Telefono/listaTelefonos?idEmpleado=${id}`)
        .then(response => {
            return response.ok ? response.json() : Promise.reject(response)
        })
        .then(responseJson => {
            const telefonos = [];
            if (responseJson.length > 0) {
                responseJson.forEach((telefono) => {
                    telefonos.push({
                        idTelefono: telefono.idTelefono,
                        descripcion: telefono.descripcion,
                        numero: telefono.numero,
                        idEmpleado: telefono.idEmpleado
                    });
                })
            }
            return telefonos;
        })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

for that you could you use AJAX, here´s an easy example.
[Ajax example](https://programarfacil.com/tutoriales/fragmentos/realizado-peticiones-ajax-desde-asp-net-mvc/)